# '404 File Not Found' and 'Inut file not specified' errors while trying to run and install laravel through Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Hello I am trying to learn Laravel for my project through homestead and I have even gone through a couple of tutorials in order to do so but despite following everything said I am still getting the error `404 File Not Found` in the browser. Where is it that I am going wrong?

Here is my Homestead.yaml file :-

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Fae
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I tried the solution given by the link [solving 404 error for laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447508/homestead-gives-404-not-found) but then I get another error `Input file not specified`. I am getting really frustrated as I am not able to find the reason for this problem, despite al my efforts

Here is the file structure in the virtual machine : present working directory is `/home/vagrant/Code`

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  4     501      80  136 May  9 21:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x  7 vagrant vagrant 4096 May  9 22:10 ../
-rw-r--r--  1     501      80 6148 May  9 21:27 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 23     501      80  782 May  9 21:36 homestead.app/
```

Here is the structure of the folder indicated by the map attribute of the yaml file in my mac : the present working directory is `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Fae`

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  23 pavan7vasan  admin  782 May  9 14:36 homestead.app
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you set up your host file as well. 192.168.10.10  homestead.app etc?

Comment: in my etc/hosts file right? yes, I did. but then I reinstalled homestead again and I did not make the change to that file since the line was already there. Perhaps this is why it is not working. Is that so?

Comment: I tried again by retyping the line in the file, still does not work

Comment: Do you have a Laravel folder into your Fae folder?

Comment: @El_Matella : Hello, Can you tell me what you mean by a Laravel folder?

Comment: Does  /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Fae/homestead.app/ exist?

Comment: Well, in your Homestead.yaml folder, you are sharing your Fae folder with /home/vagrant/Code. And in the sites descriptions, you are saying that homestead.app should point to Code/Laravel/public. That means that you should have a Laravel/public folder in your Fae folder, if you don't, that won't work...

Comment: I have a public folder in my homestead.app folder. So should I have to change the structure of the folder? meaning making changes to the public folder by placing it in a new folder called 'Laravel'?

Answer (score 1):

Hello i suggest you to use [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet) istead of homestead

This will fix all of your problem.

Comment: it could do but depends on what type of server you'll need, valet offers a good and simple/quick solution i use it, bu if you need to match your live server or your doing some server stuff then you might need something like a VM? But valet is super good and fast.

Answer (score 0):

it might be your yaml file set up

Try moving it form outside your OLD XAMPP folder and create a new one completly away for it, so edit the following:

```
  folders:
     - map: /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Fae
       to: /home/vagrant/Code
       type: "nfs"

  sites:
     - map: homestead.app
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
     hhvm: true
```

To something like.

```
  folders:
      - map: ~/Desktop/Websites
        to: /home/vagrant/Code

  sites:
      - map: domainnamehere.dev
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/domainnamehere/public
```

if you look at the folders set up in particular, perhaps changing yours to something like it, i created a Website folder on my desktop.  Looks like your using XAMPP's default location, try doing outside of XAMPP totally, separate, once updated run vagrant provision to update etc

Comment: I made no changes to the htaccess filec and I did not run XAMPP when I tried to run laravel

Comment: Hey Simon: I have solved the problem, thanks for your inputs. I think the problem was that I put the file in XAMPP which I feel was not a good idea

Comment: @NishanthSeshadri i have edited it to make it more sense.  glad to here you got it to work